# Estimating probabilities using Bayes rule?

Tags: machine-learning

I am working on a past exam paper. I am given a data set as follows:

Hair {brown, red} = {B,R},
Height {tall, short} = {T,S} and
Country {UK, Italy} = {U,I}

(B,T,U) (B,T,U) (B,T,I)

(R,T,U) (R,T,U) (B,T,I)

(R,T,U) {R,T,U) (B,T,I)

(R,S,U) (R,S,U) (R,S,I)

Question: Estimate the probabilities P(B,T|U), P(B|U), P(T|U), P(U) and P(I)

As the question states estimate, I am guessing that I don't need to calculate any values. Is it just a case of adding up how many times P(B,T|U) occurs over the whole data set e.g. (2/12) = 16%.

Then would the probability of P(U) be 0?

Comment: Not a programming question.

Comment: I don't know what their policy on homework is, but http://math.stackexchange.com/ *might* be a better place for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. Out of your 12 records, 8 are from the country UK. So P(U) should be 8/12 = 2/3 ~= .66

Bayes' theorem is P(A|B) = P(B|A)P(A)/P(B) , which you're going to need to estimate some of those probabilities.